# How to enable back button when CollapsingToolbarLayout is collapsed

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

My xml code for collapsing toolbar is,

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="left"
        app:expandedTitleMarginTop="-10dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="10dp"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/image_place_holder" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And what I have done in coding is,

```
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = null;

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
```

It is showing back icon always as it should be but I want to show/enable home (back) icon when CollapsingToolbarLayout is collapsed. How can I achieve that?
Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I've done this easily, you have to enable back navigation in toolbar simply, nothing to do with collapsing toolbar, and in manifest files tells your activity its parent class, as written parent activity name.

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    initCollapsingToolbar();
```

On collapsing:

```
 private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
    final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        boolean isShow = false;
        int scrollRange = -1;

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (scrollRange == -1) {
                scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
            }
            if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.Yoga_tips));
                isShow = true;
            } else if (isShow) {
                collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                isShow = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a flag

```
boolean FLAG_COLLAPSED = true;  //Change this according to your view
```

Then add a listener to your AppBar

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.AppBarLayout);
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) == appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            // Collapsed
            FLAG_COLLAPSED = true;
        } else if (verticalOffset == 0) {
            FLAG_COLLAPSED = false;
        } else {
            // Somewhere in between
        }
    }
}););
```

now in your backpress method,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(FLAG_COLLAPSED){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can show back icon as I wanted but now the problem is, "collapsingToolbarLayout" title is now showing when collapsed.